# SQL Query from one table and multiple columns to get the expected value

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I have a table XX_LEARN That has the following details

```
Name    Offering_course       Activity_Name      Learning Item Name         Learning Item Type
XYZ                                                    COMPUTERS              Course
XYZ      BIOTECH              BIOTECH-1                BIOTECH_OFFER          Offering
XYZ                                                    BIOTECH_OFFER          Course                                                               
DEF      MATHS                MATHS-1                  MATHS_OFFER            Offering
DEF                                                      Science                Course
```

In this table, the Offering_course and Activity_Name will only be populated when Learning Item Type = 'Offering'. When the learning item type= 'Course' only the column Learning Item Name will be populated and the Offering_course and activity Name will be null for those.

Now the expected output is from the query is -

```
Name           Activity_Name            Course Name        Learning Item Type
    XYZ                                  COMPUTERS              Course
    XYZ        BIOTECH-1                 BIOTECH                Offering                                                    
    DEF        MATHS-1                   MATHS                  Offering
    DEF                                  Science                Course
```

I.e. the Course Name column should include the Learning Item Name= 'Course' from XX_Learn and display the activity name as null for those and for Learning Item Name = 'Offering' The offering_course should be displayed in this Course Name column with the corresponding Activity_Name.

This has to be done in a single query, as I am using it in the OTBI analysis. Is there any way I can use the UNION function to achieve this?

Comment: What does this have to do with OBIEE? It doesn't use queries. It uses models.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `union` here. You could just use a `case` expression:

```
select
    name,
    activity_name,
    case when learning_item_type = 'Course'
        then learning_item_name
        else offering_course
    end course_name,
    learning_item_type
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ec7f9be549b15f6751fea3e7e3df466)**:

```
NAME | ACTIVITY_NAME | COURSE_NAME | LEARNING_ITEM_TYPE
:--- | :------------ | :---------- | :-----------------
XYZ  | null          | COMPUTERS   | Course            
XYZ  | BIOTECH-1     | BIOTECH     | Offering          
DEF  | MATHS-1       | MATHS       | Offering          
DEF  | null          | Science     | Course
```

Comment: @GMB- I have edited your query of "Insert" to show the exact issue I am facing now. Can you pls help me remove the duplicate ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ea0436a3faa35a2b8bd73054392992b9

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WINDOWS` function and simple `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
select * from
(select name, activity_name, case when learning_item_type = 'Course'
        then learning_item_name
        else offering_course
    end course_name,
    row_number() over (partition by learning_item_name order by learning_item_type desc) as rn
from your_table)
where rn = 1
```